# Is Arqade the only Q&A site like this?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Like the title indicates, **is Arqade the only 'ask & answer'-style website?** or to be a little more precise, what I want to know is "*Is there other website like Arqade but isn't about gaming?*"

The reason I'm asking this is because I saw a sort of website EXACTLY like Arqade, but about phone and phone's electronics parts. So I'm wondering if there is a website about mechanic (lego mechanic of preference).**

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 7):

Arqade is part of the network, a collection of Q&A sites. The most popular is StackOverflow.

There is indeed a site dedicated to LEGOs on the network. http://bricks.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Arqade is part of the StackExchange network, which houses tens of similar websites on similar topics. You probably saw  [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

You are probably looking for [LEGO Answers](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/).

If you are interested in checking all StackExchange websites, you can see them all [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites). Please keep in mind them their rules for asking/answering might be different, so please check their Help Center (`something.stackexchange.com/help`).